# Seeking Fostex FR2 LE case/bag/strap

Tags: fostex, bag, cases

As the title suggests I am currently seeking a carry case/bag or a good strap for my Fostex FR2 LE field recorder.
Cases such as the portabrace exceed my humble budget(up to £50), and I've been told that the alternative I was interested in, found here:

http://www.inta-audio.com/recording-c57/portable-recorders-c85/fostex-fostex-fr2le-carry-case-p2058

Is sold out.

I would be equally happy with a good strap, as the main reason for this purchase is simply in order to keep my hands free during recording; although a bag or case offering some degree of protection from the elements would be preferable.

If anyone could provide a recommendation or solution it would be very much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the shout-out, Gary. Literally forgot that I wrote that article! :-)

While I've lost any small amount of love that I had for Portabrace bags, they DO have a [model specific to the FR2LE](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/476177-REG/Porta_Brace_AR_FR2LE_AR_FR2LE_Audio_Recorder_Case.html) which AFAIK is the only one that has a flap to allow viewing of the side panel, which IMO is FAR more important and useful than the top strip of pots and meters. Operating the FR2LE out of a bag without being able to see that panel is frustrating, to say the least.

I'm sorry to report that it's out of your price range.

The other option that I went for is to go to a military supply store and get a US$15 first aid bag. Then get some clear marine vinyl. Some velcro, cutting, and sewing and you've got your own flapped, multi-pocket bag. Worked well for me until I went for the Portabrace case.

Comment: Nice idea with the military first aid bag! I'll look into that.

Answer (score 1):

Over at http://www.sonic-terrain.com Nathan Moody did an article about using bags intended for the military for audio recording purposes.

http://www.sonic-terrain.com/2010/09/portage-i-the-mil-spec-way/

You may want to look into these as well as other bags/cases as another alternative.

Comment: Thanks! That's a great link, I'll look into some military bags :)

Answer (score 1):

Check out Petrol bags.  I'm not 100% sure if they have one for the FR2 LE, but I'll bet they probably do.  Great, well-built modular/customizeable cases.  All production sound mixers I know live by them, many sound effects recordists I know use them as well.  I use one with my 702.  Personally I've had bad experiences with Portabrace and have felt their bags are flimsy and thin - the one I worked with on a regular FR2 felt more like a cloth cover tgan a solid, standing, sturdy protection bag.

Comment: +1 on Petrol bags. I own one myself, and we use two at work.